# What is the proper way to employ date2num for timestamps using candlestick_ohlc

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

My data looks like this (`Date`, `Open`, `High`, `Low`, `Close`):

```
ohlc = [
        [1502929058, 1.2652, 1.2653, 1.265, 1.2653], 
        [1502929059, 1.267, 1.267, 1.267, 1.267], 
        [1502929060, 1.2655, 1.2656, 1.2655, 1.2656], 
        [1502929061, 1.2652, 1.2653, 1.2652, 1.2653], 
        [1502929062, 1.2631, 1.2631, 1.263, 1.2631], 
        [1502929063, 1.2625, 1.2625, 1.2625, 1.2625], 
        [1502929064, 1.2619, 1.2619, 1.2619, 1.2619], 
        [1502929065, 1.2622, 1.2623, 1.2622, 1.2623], 
        [1502929066, 1.2622, 1.2623, 1.2622, 1.2623], 
        [1502929067, 1.2617, 1.262, 1.2617, 1.262]
]
```

and I'm using the code blow to plot the candlesticks:

```
for row in ohlc:
    row[0] = mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(row[0]))

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
candlestick_ohlc(ax1,ohlc,width=0.1)

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(45)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

but the candlesticks being drawn on top of each other:

[image]

as I checked the code further, I noticed that `mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(row[0]))` is actually generating dates with very minute differences (and therefore candlesticks being drawn on top of each other):

```
736558.1997453704
736558.1997569444
736558.1997685186
736558.1997800926
736558.1997916667
736558.1998032407
736558.1998148148
736558.1998263889
736558.199837963
736558.199849537
```

what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Those time stamps are all one second apart, whereas you are specifying the width as 0.1 days = 8640 s.  Not sure if you think those timestamps are correct, but if they are, suggest width = 0.1/24/3600

Comment: timestamps are correct; I misunderstood the meaning of `width`; Thanks for solving the problem.